# What is miner supposed to do when waiting for longpoll

Tags: api, development, mining-software, getwork

i am coding simple miner.
I succesfully implemented Getwork in basic form. Next thing is gonna be Longpolling. 
If i understand correctly longpoll is just connection that is waiting for next block. So, what happens when I am waiting for longpoll and submit share ? I am supposed to mine further(increase nonce and continue) or simply wait for longpoll. Using only getwork and SSE2 optimized scrypt I was able to get 5kHash/s on my i5-4670K on single thread.

Comment: I dont think you need to long poll. Check out [blocknotify](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/743).

Answer (score 2):

If you run out of work while waiting for longpoll to finish, then what you should do is submit another getwork request.

Note that just because you find a share in a particular piece of work, doesn't mean that you're done with that piece of work. There still might be shares or even a block solution in there somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Getwork (GWK) is a dieing protocol with the advent of ASICs. STM and GBT adequately support ASIC technologies. Dig into [GBT](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0022.mediawiki) some that has details about long polling, but first [read](https://deepbit.net/longpolling.php).

With the hash rates of 5KH/s and the mentioning scrypt you must be mining a little LTC, and GWK is quite adequate for that purpose.

Comment: I can't tell if this is answering the question.